# Qemu: Is it possible to have BOTH the virtual display and VGA passthrough in a Windows guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

[This guy implies that it's possible to have both the virtual display and a VGA passthrough display device active at the same time.](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/3qf15q/gpu_passthrough_one_monitor/cweqy0n/).

I've tried this, both with libvirt and with the qemu commandline.  I can have one display, or the other, but not both.  No matter what I do, I get a code 43 on the passthrough device.  But I'm using antique hardware (an old PCI Nvidia 8400GS), and that might be the problem.

Is this actually possible with a Linux host and Windows guest?  Would you mind describing your hardware, and your configuration?

My ultimate goal is to duplicate the Spice virtual display as a duplicate/clone of the Nvidia physical display.  That would allow me to run graphic-intensive applications on the hardware GPU, but still have all the convenience of a windowed virtual display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking-glass](https://looking-glass.hostfission.com/) doesn't precisely answer the question, but it solves the underlying problem nearly perfectly  -- providing GPU-accelerated VM graphics on the host desktop with the host's HID devices.  In alpha as of Dec 2017, but appears stable enough for everyday use on a single display.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not possible** at present, the Spice display driver does not appear to support Windows 10's cross-adapter display cloning feature as of yet.

**Code 43**

Turns out that the other issue I was complaining about is due to an Nvidia "bug."  When the driver detects virtualization, it throws a code 43.  NVidia has stated that this is  unintentional, but they're not planning on fixing it, either.

I solved this by downgrading my Nvidia driver to 337.88, and adding `<kvm><hidden state='on'/></kvm>` to my machine definition with `virsh edit domname`.  Apparently it's possible to get more modern drivers working by deleting a bunch of hyperv functionality, but I haven't bothered yet.